# How can I see my response from server in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My code is quite simple (Client Side):

```
Record.Router.map(function () {
   this.resource('main', { path: '/' });
});


Record.MainRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
       var response = Record.Rank.find();
       console.log(response.get('name'));
       console.log(response);
       return Record.Rank.find();
    }
});
```

My model:

```
Record.Rank = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr('integer'),
    rank: DS.attr('integer'),
    content: DS.attr('string')

});
```

I use RESTadapter:

```
Record.Store = DS.Store.extend({
   revision: 12,

    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
        namespace: 'recordApp'
    })

});
```

My Server side code (PHP):

```
<?php

    namespace RecordContainer;

    echo '{"rank":
                 {
                    "id": "1",
                    "rank": "2",
                     "content": "walla"
                  }
          }';
```

I expect to something after I issue `Record.Rank.find()` but my `console.log(response.get('name'))` logs undefined and the second `console.log(response)` show the following, no information about echo from server inside:

[image: Output of <code>console.log(response)</code>]

How do I see the response from the server, in Ember?

Comment: off the top of my head, it's `DS.attr('number')`, not `DS.attr('integer')`. you don't have to define id in your model. also, I believe store is using `DS.RESTAdapter` by default, so you can do `reopen` after `Store` definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st:** Calling `find` on a DS.Model without any parameters, i.e. `Record.Rank.find()`, is equivalent to sending a `findAll()` request to your server. In other words, it should fetch **all** `Record.Rank`. Therefore ember-data expects an array in the response of the format:

```
{
  "ranks":[
    {
      "id": "1",
      "rank": "2",
      "content": "walla"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "rank": "5",
      "content": "foo"
    }
  ]
}
```

**2nd:** Even if the response from the PHP was correct (as described above), `console.log(response.get('name'));` would probably return `undefined` since the request is not yet completed and the record(s) are not available. If you really want to access the records loaded into the store you need to place your code into a [Promise resolve callback](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/03/22/stabilizing-ember-data.html):

```
Record.MainRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
       var response = Record.Rank.find();
       response.then(function(ranks) {
         console.log(ranks.getEach('name'));
       });
       return response;
    }
});
```

Comment: Also, if you go to the Network tab of chrome dev tools and then initiate the request, you will be able to observe the request/response